# In Memoriam: Brian Stableford

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

[Brian Stableford](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?556), prolific author of over 70 novels (per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Stableford)) recently passed away on February 25th.

I first discovered him with his 1982 novel [*Journey to the Center*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?6704).  (In the trademark DAW yellow and inimitable cover.)  Other novels of mixed quality followed over the years.

The Encyclopedia of Science Fiction has an [extensive article on him](https://sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/stableford_brian_m).